# Slide div in from right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code in my Shopify Theme.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id) {
if(document.getElementById('opensign').value=='Hide Layer'){
document.getElementById('opensign').value = 'Show Layer';
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}else{
document.getElementById('opensign').value = 'Hide Layer';
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
}
}
</script>
```

Can I add so the boxes are slided in from right? Code for boxes is below:

```
<a href="#" id="opensign" onclick="setVisibility('sign');";>Sign In</a>
<div id="sign">
Blaslasd.
</div>
```

Comment: I really don't get what you want.please explain it more.where is the problem.what do you want? what do you have ?

Comment: Hi there. Sorry. I want to make the div that appears when a link with the function "setVisibility" slide in and out when shown or hidden, not just display or hide.  @ShirinAbdolahi

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css class for hiding, which should be added from the beginning:

```
.hide {
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

and a class for transitions:

```
.animated {
    transition: left 1s;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
}
```

Then in your javascript, add and remove the hide class.
You can see a demo on codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/etpDg).

Answer (score 0):

If you use shopify theme there will be jquery available.So if it is possible this will work for you :
http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/sy2upvjb/

JS

```
$('#sign').click(function () {
    if ($('#userNav').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#userNav').show('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $('#userNav').hide('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

css

```
a {
    color: #000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
}
#userNav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    background: #ff0000;
}

<a id="sign">right-to-left</a>
<div id="userNav">Blaslasd</div>
```

Comment: I see the fiddle works. But I can't get it to work in Shopify?

Comment: You have to check shopify thme for jquery. Look here if you want to use jquery https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/jquery-not-work-with-shopify-49409 . But if anyone suggested another way you have to try with pure js.Its your choice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f18h73ec/ here is the head from my store. Jquery is added there three times or so. Whats wrong? @johngrivas

Comment: Because if you see the code jquery.min.js apperas three times! Keep one

Comment: i kept  '{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' | script_tag }}'